# how to add more than one mysql statement in on statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a script for a messaging system and want to know if I can use the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` one right the other statement
so it would go like this:

1) user clicks on unread message

2) while the page is get the selected info from `SELECT` statement it updating the `message_status` from unread to read

I got the unread counter working but for it to go down I need to go to my db and change it to read for it to go down.

code i working with

```
<?php
$get_con = mysql_query("SELECT hash, user_one, user_two FROM message_group WHERE    user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'");
while($run_con = mysql_fetch_array($get_con)){
$hash = $run_con['hash'];
$user_one = $run_con['user_one'];
$user_two = $run_con['user_two'];

if($user_one == $my_id){
   $select_id = $user_two;    
}else{
   $select_id = $user_one;
}
   $user_get = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$select_id'");
   $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_get);
   $select_username = $run_user['username'];

   echo "<p><a href='conversation.php?hash=$hash'>$select_username</a></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stored procedure and call it from your script

Comment: sorry i new to php i only have some understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can run a select and update statement right after each other.

```
SELECT * from messages where messageId = 5;
Update messages SET isRead = 1 WHERE messageid = 5;
```

Comment: so for min it would be something like this

Comment: SELECT * from messages where messageId = id;
Update messages SET status = read WHERE messageid = id;

Comment: no i not added what you said to do yet i still trying to work out how it how go in to mine